# How can I stop creating a new dictionary every function call to reduce memory usage?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

My new os x ticker increases memory usage 20mb / min.

I have run it through Xcode instruments and there is no memory leak.

It runs a timer when the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` that calls `checkDNS()`

checkDNS() creates a new dictionary `jsonResult2`, performs an API call, and then prints the result in the console.

I believe the problem is that every 5 seconds, I am creating a new dictionary, getting the values from the API call and writing them to that dictionary. I assumed it would just overwrite the old one since it's still called `jsonResult2` but it seems that lots of memory is being used in a perfect positive gradient.

[image: Here is the memory profile]

This is my `checkDNS()` function.

```
 func checkDNS() {

    request3.URL = NSURL(string: urlDNS)
    request3.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request3, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data, error2) -> Void in

        if data == nil
        {
            println("no data returned from API")
            return
        }

        let jsonResult2: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: self.error) as NSDictionary

        if let dns = jsonResult2["dns"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
            if let dnsCompany = dns["geo"] as? String {
                self.dnsCompanyOut = dnsCompany
            }
            if let dnsIP = dns["ip"] as? String {
                self.dnsIPOut = dnsIP
            }
        }

        println(self.dnsCompanyOut)
        println(self.dnsIPOut)

    })
}
```

What can I do to resolve this? I attempted to move the creation / initialisation of `jsonResult2` to `applicationDidFinishLaunching` but it required me converting it to optional (?) which downcasted it later and I got more errors.

What is the most efficient way for me to do this without hogging all the memory and creating all new variables every 5 seconds?

Thanks so much, almost finished my app but I'm struggling right at the end here debugging. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: (1) You don't need to cast to NSDictionary before casting to [String: AnyObject]. Let it just infer AnyObject? (2) if you don't want to re-create the dictionary store it as a variable class (or struct) property.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: Like any other class (or struct) property, create a 
`var jsonResult:[String:AnyObject]?`
or 
`var jsonResult2 = [String: AnyObject]()`
outside the method in the main body of the class (or struct). 
In the method use
 `if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:nil, error: self.error) as? [String: AnyObject] {jsonResult2 = json}`
in place of
`let jsonResult2: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: self.error) as NSDictionary`

Comment: Thanks i'll fiddle around. I get a [String: AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: I mean I get a unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping value

Comment: If using the optional version, you need to either `if let` the dictionary or use `if let dns = jsonResult2?["dns"] as? [String: AnyObject] {}`  - note the question mark after jsonResult2. To avoid "unexpectedly found nil" don't force unwrap. `if let` the data going into NSJSONSerialization and `if let` the  result coming out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iVar, then it would overwrite and would fix your issue (if that is really your issue ^^)

Also, i'm not sure how this would go with your code as a whole but, couldn't you set your dictionary to `nil` when you're done using it?

Comment: I can't set jsonResult2 to as I cannot convert let value to jsonResult2